# the spring web isn't working student/register.html

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

the problem is that try to get the register.html form the controllerbut I can't figuer it out?
this is ThymeleafApplication.java  code

```
package com.cydeo.spring10thymeleaf;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ThymeleafApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ThymeleafApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**The controller.java code:**

[image]

**The webpage:**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems odd that you are getting a 404, which is what that error message is, it would seem you either don't have the correct path for the request or the controller isn't registered correctly.

The student controller should work given the example code but something in the greater project isn't 100% correct.

A stripped-down working version I posed [here](https://github.com/beckje01/stackoverflow-77773332).

I would start with making sure any controller was working before layering in the nesting but maybe this example will give you the place to start.

Comment: Hi jeff,
Thank you for your answer , I do have the same thing with the code you have in the link.

Comment: the line of code isn't shown :
```
System.out.println("I have been called.");
```
I don't why and I still getting the same problem.

Comment: If you are running and calling the project are you getting an error message or does it show the webpage?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a WebMvcConfigurer class setup?  This will let spring know where to find the view *register.html*

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc // Enable Spring MVC
@ComponentScan("com.cydeo.controller") // Will scan com.cydeo.controller for @Controller classes
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
    private static final String TEMPLATE_PREFIX = "classpath:/WEB-INF/templates/";
    private static final String TEMPLATE_SUFFIX = ".html";

    /**
     * Thymeleaf View Resolver
     * Resolves Thymeleaf template views from logical view names
     *
     * @param templateEngine
     */
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine)
    {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    /**
     * Template Engine
     * Processes the templates and renders the results
     *
     * @param templateResolver
     */
    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver)
    {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        return templateEngine;
    }

    /**
     * Template Resolver
     * Loads the Thymeleaf templates
     *
     */
    @Bean
    public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver()
    {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix(TEMPLATE_PREFIX);
        templateResolver.setSuffix(TEMPLATE_SUFFIX);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML");
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

[image]